# What happened to Rocky in The Lazarus Effect?

Tags: character, the-lazarus-effect

Rocky was a dog who played a principal role in the first half of "The Lazarus Effect".  Weird things happening to the dog gave a foreshadowing of what was about to happen to the humans.

But once the film gets in to full swing, Rocky sort of disappears and is not heard or seen again. What happened to him?

I figure there are some alternatives...

- he escaped and ran away and the scene wound up on the cutting room floor
- he got killed off screen and the scene wound up on the cutting room floor
- he morphed into a somebody's dead body
- he is lurking about waiting to go full hulk on Zoe

Which of these (or some alternate view) would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implied that he's killed, but I'm guessing they wanted to keep it off-screen to maintain their PG-13 rating.

There's one point in the film when he's in a room with Zoe, and the view cuts to outside the room, and you hear him yelp in pain.  Unfortunately, I can't find a clip of this on YouTube.